# How to properly test function calls inside Redux Toolkit's createAsyncThunks - Jest + Redux Toolkit

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux Toolkit's createAsyncThunk for an API request. This specific thunk is calling a sepparate non-anonymous function as its second parameter:

```js
export const onInfoSubmit = createAsyncThunk('info/onInfoSubmit', handlePayload)
```

The handlePayload function goes like:

```js
export async function handlePayload (data, { dispatch, rejectWithValue, getState }) {
  dispatch(updateInfo({ isLoadingInfoRequest: true }))

  if (!isFeatureEnabled(FEATURE_NAME)) {
    return handleUpdateInfo(data, { dispatch, rejectWithValue, getState })
  }

  return thirdPartyApiCall()
    .then((response) => {
      data.thirdPartyResponse = response
      return handleUpdateInfo(data, { dispatch, rejectWithValue, getState })
    })
}
```

The handleUpdateInfo function is used to set Session Storage items, send a PUT request with the dynamically created payload with an axios call and, in case of failures or in case of response errors, trigger reject accordingly.

My question is, how could I test if, for instance, calling mockStore.dispatch(onInfoSubmit) calls the handlePayload function, and further on (if handlePayload calls handleUpdateInfo, for instance)?

I have tried the following approaches:

```js
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const middlewares = [thunk]
const mockStore = configureStore(middlewares)

jest.mock('./InfoSlice.js', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('./InfoSlice'),
  handlePayload: jest.fn((data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(data))),
  handleUpdateInfo: jest.fn((data) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(data)))
}))

describe('InfoSlice unit tests', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'sessionStorage', {
      value: {
        getItem: jest.fn(() => null),
        setItem: jest.fn(() => null),
        removeItem: jest.fn(() => null)
      },
      writable: true
    })
  })
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks()
  })

  const initialState = {
    loginInfo: {
      userName: 'test@test.com',
      email: 'test@test.com'
    },
    verifyEmailResponse: {},
    email: {
      loginInfo: {
        email: 'test@test.com'
      }
    }
  }

it('onInfoSubmit calls handlePayload', async () => {
    const store = mockStore(initialState)
    await store.dispatch(onEmailSubmit({
      loginInfo: {
        userName: 'new@test.com',
        email: 'new@test.com',
      }
    }))
    expect(handlePayload).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
```

But for some reason, handlePayload never gets called in this test.
Trying to check if handleUpdateInfo gets called in the same manner, also results in a broken test...
Besides, I cannot really seem to get any of the mock functions called on these tests.

Any tips on this issue will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you are mocking the export with the name `handlePayload` - but inside that file, `onInfoSubmit` has still been created with the local function definition. You would probably have to split those over a file boundary to make that work.

Generally though, that test would not be testing anything besides the question if you have actually written `handlePayload` in that line - the test does not give you any confidence that your code is really working.

I'd recommend to mock as little as possible of your own code, but only mock things like apis (using `msw` for example) and `window.localStorage`. Then run your thunks in a real-life environment and see it your component works. We recommend doing real-life integration tests in the [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests) as that will give you the most confidence on actual functionality, not just implementation details.

Comment: Hey, phry, thank you very much for your answer. It does help me understand that my test is not really that useful in this scenario.

I've chosen to restart and to not mock the handlePayload and handleUpdateInfo functions, instead focusing on the axios calls.

I have added a few console.logs to the original functions to see what is going on. Actually, when calling the onInfoSubmit thunk, handlePayload does get called, but I can't seem to get into the if, neither into the returned thirdPartyApiCall promise inside handlePayload, at least the logs are not showing up...

Comment: Just noticed that the payload sent to onInfoSubmit is undefined...
Maybe I am calling it wrong?

I am using onInfoSubmit(payload).

Comment: You need to call `dispatch(onInfoSubmit(data))`

Comment: Hello again, Phry. Once again, thanks for your reply.
After some debugging, I finally realized that the mocked store for testing was not providing a fairly important property for our UserSlice. Since this property was undefined, tests were breaking before reaching any function calls.

Again, thank you for your comments!